# Locus of complex number in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, circles, locus

I have the following complex number:

$G = \xi + i\eta$

$\xi = 1-\sigma(1-\cos\phi_m)$

$\eta = -\sigma\sin\phi_m$

how can I find the locus of this complex number? I am told without proof that it is a circle of radius $\sigma$ and centre $1-\sigma$ but cannot even begin to think where this came from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
G & = 1-\sigma + \sigma \cos\phi_m -i\sigma \sin \phi_m\\
& = 1-\sigma + \sigma(\cos\phi_m - i \sin\phi_m)\\
& = 1-\sigma + \sigma e^{-i\phi_m}
\end{align}$$

And this is the equation of a circle wih radius $\sigma$ and center $1-\sigma$.

Comment: Can you explain why that prescribes a circle with that radius and center?

Comment: $e^{-i\phi_m}$ describes a unit circle, so $\sigma e^{-i\phi_m}$ describes a circle with radius $\sigma$. $1-\sigma$ translates this circle. It translates the center $0$ to $1-\sigma$.

Comment: as extra clarification: $e^{-i\phi_m}$ is a parameterization of a unit circle since according to Eulers formula $e^{-i\phi_m} = \cos(-\phi_m) + i\sin (-\phi_m)$. You could prove that this is the parameterization of a unit circle by proving $|e^{-i\phi_m}| = 1\; \forall \phi_m$. Like this: $|\cos(-\phi_m)+i\sin(-\phi_m)|^2 = \cos^2(-\phi_m) + \sin^2(-\phi_m) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Think of $<\xi,\eta>$ as a vector in $\mathcal{R}^2$. We can write it as:

$
\begin{align}
\left<\xi,\eta\right> &= \left<1-\sigma+\sigma\cos\phi_m,-\sigma\sin\phi_m\right> \\
 &= \left<1-\sigma,0\right> + \sigma\left<\cos\phi_m,-\sin\phi_m\right>
\end{align}
$

The part that doesn't depend on $\phi_m$ gives us a center of $\left<1-\sigma,0\right>$, which corresponds to the real number $1-\sigma$. The part with the sine and cosine of $\phi_m$, gives us a circle traced out in a clockwise direction, with a radius of $\sigma$.

Comment: So, the locus is the curve for all values of $\phi_m$ between 0 and $2\pi$?

Comment: Yes, the interval $[0,2\pi)$ is sufficient to give us the whole circle.